# How to add a foreign key to an existing table

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite

Hi I'm using laravel 10 and wanted to add a foreign key to an already existing table

```
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();

        Schema::table('channels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignIdFor(App\Models\User::class)
            ->after('name')
            ->constrained();
        });

        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    }

    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('channels', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropForeign(['user_id']);
            $table->dropColumn('user_id');
        });
    }
```

I disabled the foreign key verification with command Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(), but I still get an error.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (Connection: sqlite, SQL: alter table "channels" add
column "user_id" integer not null)

Please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you want to create a foreign key and it translates to an alter that would add/modify a column to not nullable, but a default value of null.

You can explicitly state a not null default, like

```
->default(0)
```

or set the column to be nullable

```
->nullable()
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the problem remains the same

Comment: @NikitaBalashov can you edit your question and add the exact way you tried to do it?